# Get a length/size of message field value

Tags: kibana, elasticsearch-painless

I try to make a scripted fields with size of message field value. I tried

```
doc['message'].value.getSize() 
doc['message'].value.size()
```

I tried also with `['message.keyword']` but nothing. I have `[ ]` in preview. Where am I wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try`params._source.message.length()`.